# Change font size for blockquotes

Tags: csquotes

Using the [eisvogel template](https://github.com/Wandmalfarbe/pandoc-latex-template), which uses csquote and Koma-Script packages, I'd like to change the font size of blockquotes to small/10-11 pt.

Thanks.

Comment: The manual describes code-block-font-size as a variable.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you how to transfer the LaTeX code to code your pandoc export engine understands. But in the end in the LaTeX file that's compiled you need to have this code:

```
\AddToHook{env/quote/before}{\small}
```

By the way, I've copied this code from the very helpful manual "LaTeX’s hook management", p. 5. Should be part of your LaTeX installation.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by adding the following to the LaTeX template:

```
usepackage{relsize}
```

and then adding {\relsize{-1]} to the {customblockquote} element:

```
\definecolor{blockquote-border}{RGB}{221,221,221}
\definecolor{blockquote-text}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\newmdenv[rightline=false,bottomline=false,topline=false,linewidth=4pt,linecolor=blockquote-border,skipabove=\parskip,]{customblockquote}
\renewenvironment{quote}{\begin{customblockquote}\list{}{\rightmargin=1em\leftmargin=1em\relsize{-1}}%
\item\relax\color{blockquote-text}\ignorespaces}{\unskip\unskip\endlist\end{customblockquote}}
```